# Children component gets props as undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to pass props to my children components which are under the controller. I'm using redux and react-router for navigation. The problem is that everything is fine in the controller, it gets its initial props, but when I'm passing them to a child I have an undefined either the constructor or in render function. Here is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import moment from 'moment'

import LawsuitSchedule from '../components/LawsuitSchedule'
import LawsuitCalendar from '../components/LawsuitCalendar'

class LawsuitScheduleContainer extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render () {
    let {schedule} = this.props
    console.log(schedule)

    return (
      <LawsuitCalendar initialDate={schedule.initialDate}
                       selectedDate={schedule.selectedDate}
                       scheduledDates={schedule.scheduledDates}/>,
        <LawsuitSchedule/>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  schedule: state.schedule,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LawsuitScheduleContainer)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import momentPropTypes from 'react-moment-proptypes'
import moment from 'moment'
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'
import '../styles/lawsuitCalendar.css'

export default class LawsuitCalendar extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(props)
      }
  propTypes = {
    selectedDate: momentPropTypes.momentString,
    scheduledDates: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  }

  handleChange = (date) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedDate: date,
    })
  }

  render () {
    let {selectedDate, scheduledDates} = this.props
    let highlightWithRanges = [
      {
        'scheduled-date': scheduledDates,
      },
    ]
    return (
      <DatePicker
        inline
        selected={selectedDate}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        highlightDates={highlightWithRanges}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replying, but it's just syntax from html5 for self-closing tags, not a mistake

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in another component, which renders `LawsuitCalendar` too. I have no clue why it was displayed only once, but I have solved my problem with props -- I just didn't pass them. I've added it, maybe someone can answer why has that happened?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import matchSorter from 'match-sorter'
import LawsuitCalendar from '../components/LawsuitCalendar'
import '../styles/lawsuitGrid.css'
import data from '../utils/data.json'

export default class LawsuitSchedule extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row className="show-grid">
          <Col md={4}><LawsuitCalendar/></Col>
          <Col md={8}>
            <ReactTable data={data}
            ...
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}
```